# Custom serialization of JDK5 Enum in Axis 1.2 on client-side

Tags: java, soap, enums, axis

I am migrating a SOAP web service to JDK1.5.
I have took advantage of native java enums in the new code.
For some reasons, I'm stuck with Axis 1.2 and it does not natively support JDK5 "enums".

I have found a tutorial on how to implement custom a serialization / deserialization for java enums:
http://www.developpez.net/forums/d236564/java/developpement-web-java/web-services/utiliser-type-enum-jdk5-axis/ (in French).

I have been able to successfully register those custom serialization handlers on the server side via the use of "typeMapping" elements in the ".wsdd" file.

However, I can't figure out how to register the same classes on the client side, as I do not have a ".wssd" file here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Raphael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found how to manually register a custom type mapping.
I do it when creating an instance of a **Service** :

```
service = new Service(); 

// Get default type mapping
TypeMapping tmap = DefaultTypeMappingImpl.getSingletonDelegate();

// Register our custom serializer / deserializer 
tmap.register(
        MyCustomClass.class, 
        MyCustomClassQName, 
        new MyCustomSerizalizerFactory(), 
        new MyCustomDeserizalizerFactory());

// Add it back to the service
service.getTypeMappingRegistry().register(
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", // Default encoding
        tmap);
```

I don't know whether it is the right way to do it, but it works !